# What is the purpose of nameidentifier claim?

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, federated-identity

What the claim of type `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` should be used for?

This is the main question, and here are additional ones.

How does it differ from `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` claim?

Is it permanent for particular user as opposed to name claim?

Is it globally-scoped or IdP-scoped?

Comment: Did you ever find an answerto this, Anton?

Comment: Hi, @TommyJakobsen. Unfortunately, no. In the end, we didn't use this claim in our application.

Answer (score 63):

`Name`, is just that a name.  If we're talking person, think "Eric"; a server "file01".

A `NameIdentifier` is the ID for an object.  Turning back to our person object, Eric's UserID might be 435 in your database.  For the server the Identifier could be something like a FQDN or a SID.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149492/what-is-the-purpose-of-saml-2-subject-name-identifier), apparently Name Identifier was a SAML 1.1 property, and is being supplanted by `NameID` in SAML 2.0.

#### Unique or Not?

I wanted to address @Jason's comment and @nzpcmad's post.  I don't see uniqueness as a clear cut requirement.   The question is tagged [adfs2.0](/questions/tagged/adfs2.0) but the schema referenced is owned by OASIS. So those are the two parties interpretations we need to balance.

Microsoft's stance for ADFS is clearly that there is a unique requirement.  We see that in the "[The Role of Claims](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913589.aspx)" article.   No doubt ADFS casts a big shadow, but this seems like an implementation detail.

Looking at the [SAML 1.1 spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/3406/oasis-sstc-saml-core-1.1.pdf), however, I see no such assertion.    The closest we get in section 2.4.2.2 of spec is:

> The  element specifies a subject by a combination of a
>   name qualifier, a name, and a format.  The  element has 
>   the following attributes:
>      ...
>    NameQualifier[optional] The security or administrative domain that 
>   qualifies the name of the subject.  This attribute provides a means 
>   to federate names from disparate user stores without collision.

The text of the spec tells me that I need to be able to find a person using a combination of the three attributes, but it makes no assertion as to uniqueness.   Couldn't I have two entries that point to the same user?  Seems so.   Moreover, wouldn't' the spec indicate the `NameQualifier` attribute was required in cases where `NameIdentifier` was insufficient to uniquely identify the name?

So what's this all lead to?

- Be careful, unqiue is likely safer.
- Dig into your providers stance on the topic.

Comment: I think nzpcmad's answer adds more clarity here. A Name is not just a name if it is supposed to be unique. I was confused about whether I should use Name or NameIdentifier to store usernames. Now I know.

Answer (score 14):

Per [The Role of Claims](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913589%28WS.10%29.aspx),

Name
 The unique name of the user

Name Identifier
 The SAML name identifier of the user

These two claims are part of the group of claims that AD FS 2.0 configures by default.

This implies that they are IP scoped.

e.g. when you log in to Google using ACS, "nameidentifier" is the unique GUID associated with your account by Google whereas name is your Google login e.g. "tim.smith@gmail.com".

Comment: Thank you, @nzpcmad, for your attention. However it is still uncler to me what does "name identifier" mean. There is no explaination in "The SAML name identifier of the user" phrase.

Answer (score 12):

`ClaimTypes.Name` is for *username* and `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` specifies *identity* of the user as object perspective. If you add them in a kind of `ClaimIdentity` object that provides you to reach `User.Identity` methods(for example in the dotnet world) which are `GetUserName()` and `GetUserId()`.

Answer (score -1):

The `nameidentifier` claim should be used for getting a unique user name.

**For Windows Authentication:**

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier    domain\warlock

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name  0#.w|domain\warlock

domain\warlock is a Windows Login name

**For Claims Based Authentiacation:**

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier    warlock@localhost.com

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name  05.t|myidentityprovider|warlock@localhost.com

email was specified as the Identifier Claim

As you can see `.../identity/claims/name` describes name and identity provider as well.

Comment: This example is not very clear, goes against the other two answers, and has no supporting evidence.  Accepted answers say nameidentifier should basically be a unique integer or GUID and name should be the unique username.

Comment: Links are broken