# What is the purpose of SAML 2 Subject Name Identifier?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth

When doing authn against a SAML 2 IdP, what does the Subject Name Identifier supposed to be for? Does it track each user login?

I'm wondering if my SAML 2 service provider application should track these for different users. Since they are transient, they can be different for different logins (so I would need to track using a collection hanging off the user account).

Answer (score 11):

Name Identifier contains several attributes.

The first attribute is *NameQualifier*, which specifies the security domain of the user at the IDP. Security domain is useful to disambiguate different users that use the same name identifier.

The second attribute is *SPNameQualifier*, which specifies the security domain of the user at the SP.

The third attribute is *Format*, which specifies how the name identifier should be interpreted.

For example, *Email Address* name identifier format is used when the user wants to use the same name identifier in IDP and SP. This means that if the user is login as alice@domain.com in IDP, the user is also login as alice@domain.com in SP.

Another example, Persistent Identifier is used when the user does not want to use the same name identifier in IDP and SP. This means that a user can login as alice@idp.com in IDP, but login as bob@sp.com in SP. This is achieved by using an identifier, such as 12345, agreed by IDP and SP, which is mapped to alice@idp.com in IDP and mapped to bob@sp.com in SP. Persistent Identifier is useful when you do not want the SP to know the name identifier of the user in IDP.

Answer (score 9):

The `<NameIdentifier>` element is a SAML 1.1 concept. It has been superseded by the `<NameID>` element which identifies the subject. NameID is not necessarily transient - see section 8.3 of the SAML 2.0 core [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)