# How to get Azure AD Object ID in a hosted MVC App?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have a .Net Core 3.1 MVC app hosted as Azure Web App and enabled Express Authentication. Now in the code, I want the Azure AD Object ID (in Controller/View). In all the examples and samples, I see multiple ways to get information about User details like Name etc. but could not find anything about getting the Object ID. How to get the same?

My Controller is pretty simple, like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

In View, index.cshtml is also very generic.

In the startup.cs, I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Please let me know a way to get the Azure AD Object ID in the Index() method in the Controller.

Comment: the object id is an internal Azure AD identifier. You must query Azure AD to find it

Answer (score 0):

I believe the objectid is being passed as a `oid` claim. It is part of the `id_token` you get in Express Authentication.

[How do I get an OID claim in ASPCore from Azure B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978403/how-do-i-get-an-oid-claim-in-aspcore-from-azure-b2c)

> http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier

`User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value`

Comment: I did some research on it. Looks like it should return me the oid as intended, however I am getting null. Is there any config I need to set up in Azure, or what am I missing?

Comment: I could get the user's objectID in .cshtml by calling the method `@User.GetObjectId()`. I verified it in the sample at this [line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/fab815ee50017d0009ce4d699547e7721ceaa248/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L6).