# Clarity on UID, OID, SUB string/guid and how to fetch in Asp.Net Core w/AAD IDP

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to get a unique userid, preferably as a GUID, using AAD as the IDP in an Asp.Net Core app so I can manage identity related activities in a db, using the GUID as a PK, or at least a reference column.  I could use some clarity on how to get this id.

I've read:

- The uid (user id) is the same as the sub claim, which changes per app (e.g., v1, v2, adminapp, clientapp, etc. would return different uid's for the same user identity).
- The oid (object id) is unique to the IDP, so it will give the same id for an identity/user regardless of the app. So, I don't know why you would use uid/sub vs. oid if I understand this correctly.

UID's can be obtained via

`var userid = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

But this returns a string and not a GUID... Alternatively, I could use the slightly more error-prone ("uid" not strongly typed like NameIdentifier) statement which does returns a GUID:

`var userid = (ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "uid")?.Value);`

The two statements above do not return the same results, leading me to wonder what exactly is NameIdentifier.

[image]

Attempting to get the mysterious oid fails, as no oid claim exists and an exception is thrown:

`var userId = Guid.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "oid")?.Value);`

So, what is the recommended practice for obtaining a unique user id for an app that will remain the same throughout variations of the app? UID via FirstOrDefault statement or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the OID by using Microsoft.Identity.Web and `var userID = User.GetObjectId();`

Found via the following references:

- [What claim to use to reliably id the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference) (TL/DR: OID)
- [How to get the OID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978403/how-do-i-get-an-oid-claim-in-aspcore-from-azure-b2c) (TL/DR: User.GetObjectId() via Microsoft.Identity.Web)
- [Claims Mapping and how to clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (TL/DR: JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();)